# How can I disable duplicate post check in WordPress importer?

Tags: wordpress, import

I am looking for a way to import a batch of posts with many posts with the same name and publication date.

Code in class-wp-import.php:

```
$post_exists = apply_filters( 'wp_import_existing_post', $post_exists, $post );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

disable WordPress default importer duplicate checking:
eg: in functions.php

```
add_filter( 'wp_import_existing_post', function ( $post_exists ) {
    $post_exists = false;

    return $post_exists;
} );
```